# Code changes - Python - Piphone - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python

Right now I'm working hard to finish a project named Pihpone; I've been following the adafruit tutorial and I've also bought all the items that were suggested by them

The problem is that..the code was written for 2,8" while I have a 3.5" screen

I've succeeded in making some changes like modifying the 320x240 with 480x320

Still not enough but I dont know what to do further; pls come with any suggestion;

Here are the screenshots:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvFLZ.jpg)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ejvg.jpg)

https://github.com/climberhunt/Piphone/archive/master.zip
From there you can download the code made by Adafruit; you can find the code in piphone.py.

Comment: Hi, instead of the link could you post a screenshot somewhere? I think you can attach images in your post even with minimal reputation. Also, some code samples would help - try to isolate the problem to the smallest amount of code.

Comment: You see..in the code from the link above in my original post its a section with buttons; those buttons have coordinates: X, Y, Height and width; I think there is the problem but I am not too sure; Its just an opionin of mine

Comment: There is smth like # Screen 0 for numeric input
  [Button(( 30,  0,320, 60), bg='box'),
   Button(( 30, 60, 60, 60), bg='1',     cb=numericCallback, value=1),
   Button(( 90, 60, 60, 60), bg='2',     cb=numericCallback, value=2),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `piphone.py` appears to be using the [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/) module to do the graphics. The problem is all the **hardcoded** coordinates and sizes for things like the `Button`s. To fix this, the values must be computed at run-time and depend on the display resolution. Line 255 sets the display mode.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(modes[0], FULLSCREEN, 16)
```

After doing that, you can get a video display information object from [`pygame.display.Info()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info) and obtain the width and height of the current video mode, then use those values to scale and position the buttons.

You may also need to create different sets of image files for the various sizes of display you want the program to support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I'll try like that; hope it will work

Comment: You're welcome. It may be a fair amount of work. One way folks do this is by laying out all the GUI elements on an idealized grid, say 1000x1200, to get starting values. Then, after the actual display size is known, compute x and y scaling factors possibly also with x and y offsets that will map coordinates and size if the virtual display onto the real one.

Comment: God...this I don't know to do..-_-    aa..I really wonder if somewhere on the internet is not any version of this piphone soft but for a 3.5" screen

Comment: If the display sizes don't vary too greatly, you may be able to get by with just adding an x and y value to all the position coordinates and leaving the sizes alone.

Comment: that's not to difficult I guess; no, of course they do not vary too much; in the end..it's a difference of only 0.7" and that's not much but meh

Comment: Just add ½ the difference of screen widths to the X positions, and same of the screen height difference to the Y's. That will distribute the extra space around the edges evenly.

Comment: I understand now..very well then; after work I'll look further to these changes; thx a lot^^